# How to select 3 different tables

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have 3 tables:

1. Provider (id_provider, provider_name, etc.)
2. Quote (id_quote, origin, destination, etc.)
3. Price (id_provider, id_quote, price)

I would like to show the information in the following columns:

```
origin   | destination | provider name 1 | provider name 2 | provider name 3
q.origin | q.destin    | price(quote     |  price(quote)   |  price(quote)
```

the price table will link prices of several providers from the same quote (flight).

I hope someone here can help me out with this. I've been trying different approaches with inner join but I can't bring the providers as column to show their prices for each quote in a single line.

Comment: Please tag the DBMS you are using.

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data and desired outcome that you want.

Comment: To place providers into different columns you need to `PIVOT` the data. Different database vendors provide a different syntax for this style of query. That is why you NEED to add a tag which tells us which database you are using. We don't ask for the sake of asking, we actually need to know.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional aggregation works in any database:

```
SELECT qt.origin, qt.destination,
       MAX(CASE WHEN p.provider_name = 'provider name 1' then pr.price END) as price_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN p.provider_name = 'provider name 2' then pr.price END) as price_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN p.provider_name = 'provider name 3' then pr.price END) as price_3
FROM Price pr JOIN
     Quote q
     ON q.id_quote = pr.id_quote JOIN
     Provider p
     ON p.id_provider = pr.id_provider
GROUP BY q.origin, q.destination;
```

This also requires a fixed list of providers.  If you don't know the providers you want in the columns, then you have a problem that requires dynamic SQL -- and a simple `select` cannot do the job.

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL Server (2008+) one could use PIVOT for this.

**Example:**

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
     qt.origin, qt.destination, prv.provider_name, prc.price
   FROM Price prc
   JOIN Quote qt ON (qt.id_quote = prc.id_quote)
   JOIN Provider prv ON (prv.id_provider = prc.id_provider)
   WHERE prv.provider_name IN 
         (
          'provider name 1',
          'provider name 2',
          'provider name 3'
         )
   ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY qt.origin, qt.destination, prv.id_provider ORDER BY qt.id_quote DESC)
) src
PIVOT  
(  
     MAX(prc.price)  
     FOR prv.provider_name IN 
         (
          [provider name 1],
          [provider name 2],
          [provider name 3]
         )
) pvt
```

The column names need to be hardcoded.
But if one doesn't want to hardcode the names, then [Dynamic SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) would be needed.